# Neighbours in a circle with similar interests

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried this problem (from British FST $2011$) for a long time, with an induction and swapping approach, but nothing has worked. Any ideas please?

**Problem:**

There is a conference attended by $512$ mathematicians, who have been assigned to share $256$ twin rooms. Each is interested in some subset of the following nine subjects: algebraic topology, Banach spaces, combinatorics, differential manifolds, Euclidean geometry, fluid dynamics, group theory, harmonic analysis and inequalities. Every mathematician has a distinct set of interests (so, in particular, one is interested in nothing, and one in everything).

Show that, at the conference dinner, they can be sat in one big circle such that everyone is sat next to his roommate, and such that, if two people are sat next to one another who are not roommates, then they have sets of interests which are identical except for one subject.

Comment: In the induction, was the number you were increasing the number of mathematitians or the number of subjects?

Comment: I was increasing both at the same time; for n subjects there are precisely 2^n mathematicians, 2^{n-1} rooms. However for the inductive step I can't seem to 'fit' the new mathematicians in.

Comment: The roommates sitting next to each other confuses me. Is that any sort of restriction at all? We don't know how the rooms were assigned, so can we choose any way we want, or is it saying that our solution must be applicable  for every different possible room assignment?

Comment: @Arby Given the way it's phrased, I believe it means that for every possible room assignment, there exists a circular arrangement such that any two neighbors in the circle are either roommates or have the same interests except for a single subject.

Comment: What exactly does "have sets of interest which are identical except for one subject" mean? If person 1 has interests $\{A,B\}$ and person 2 has interests $\{A,C\}$ are their sets identical except for one subject?

Comment: @Jens As I see it, the desired interpretation seems to be that each mathematician is associated with a bit string of length 9, where each position corresponds to a fixed subject, and the bit at that position is 1 if the mathematician is interested in the subject, otherwise 0. Two mathematicians are then said to "have identical interests except for one subject" if the Hamming distance of their two bit strings is 1.

Comment: Sorry if we don't allow necroing (I'm kinda new here) but I saw this problem and thought it was interesting. Try considering a Hamiltonian cycle on a 9th dimensional hypercube, and connect roommates on this hypercube. How would you reconcile the paths to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I didn't realize this was such an old post, but someone may find this interesting. I've edited this to include a proper citation.

This is a whimsical application of a theorem from the paper

*Fink, Jiří*, [**Perfect matchings extend to Hamilton cycles in hypercubes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2007.02.007), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. B 97, No. 6, 1074-1076 (2007). [ZBL1126.05080](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1126.05080).

Consider $2^n$ mathematicians as nodes in a complete graph, each labeled by a unique binary sequence of length $n$ describing a set of interests. Considering only the edges that connect nodes whose corresponding sequences differ only by one bit gives an $n$-dimensional hypercube subgraph. The assignment of roommates corresponds to a perfect matching on the complete graph. A matching is a set of edges such that every vertex is incident with at most one edge. The matching is perfect if every vertex is incident with one of its edges.

The theorem tells us that for every perfect matching $P$ on the complete graph described above, there is another perfect matching $R$ on the $n$-dimensional hypercube subgraph such that $P\cup R$ is a Hamiltonian circuit. This Hamiltonian circuit gives an assignment of mathematicians around the round table as sought.